# SQL Server Transactional Replication Distribution Database not keeping up

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, transactional-replication

We have following setup at the moment:

8 Cluster servers (SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition) talking to 2,000 store servers in the field via Merge Replication.

The 8 servers are replicating to a reporting DB server (SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise).

We have partitioned tables using the server ID from 8 servers on this reporting database so we can have data in one database and not going to 8 individual databases. It using Push Transactional Replication.

We would like to do the following:

Create a New Transactional Publication on this reporting DB server which would replicate to 2 SQL Server 2012 Standard nodes for scale-out.  We've implemented this, and it's working as expected.

Issue we are running into:

One of the articles gets about 3 million updates (i.e. Delete and Insert coming from 8 cluster servers) twice in the morning and twice in the evening.

This causes a lot of activity in the Distribution database under `MSRepl_Commands` table, which the reporting server is not keeping up with causing the entire replication to the "scale out" nodes to come to a halt.  Commands keep piling up under the Distribution database at the reporting database server.

How can we make sure these Updates under this particular Article are getting cleaned up quickly at the Distribution database and keep replication to scale out nodes in good condition?

UPDATE: I am constantly seeing blocks when Distribution Cleanup job is running:

"Update MSsubscriptions..." is creating block ON this statement "UPDATE MSdistribution_history..."

One of the column in this particular article is VARBINARY(MAX) would that make a difference with large batch of INSERT and DELETE?

Comment: Is your distribution database on the reporting database server?

Comment: Yes it is on the reporting server database

Comment: Need to determine where the latency is first.  Is it the logreader reading the tranlog, or writing to the distribution database?  Is it the distribution agent reading the transactions, or writing to the subscriber?  Have you run a tracer token?  Do you have undistributed transactions?  It could be that you will need to move the distribution database to another server.

Comment: I have added that article back to the publication. I will check above and post it with that information, thank you Stacy

Comment: After adding article back, I see Distribution Cleanup agent is getting blocked by itself, following proc is creating block:
EXEC dbo.sp_MSdistribution_cleanup (retention is set to 72)

on to :

sys.sp_MSadd_distribution_history;1

this is causing replication transaction not to continue towards subscriber. 

Any guideance in this would be appriciated.

Comment: More info:

Ran Tracer and Publisher to Distributor is 00:00:03, but Distributor to Subscriber is not showing time and keep saying "Pending..." since last 10mins.

Comment: This morning MSRepl_Commands is already back to 40Million records and stream to subscriber failed many times throughout the night. I have removed the article from the publication so other articles in this publication can catch up. I have added couple updated information in above question to see if that helps.

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Update:

I created separate publication under 8 Cluster servers from which reporting server was getting the data towards SQL Scale Out server with this 1 article. It's working successfully and is keeping up with the data under each of the 8 cluster servers.

So, [Distribution] database is the one not keeping up on the reporting server if I add this 1 article due to heavy Delete and Insert, but as same load is distributed among 8 cluster servers causing [Distribution] database not to bog down with cleanup process.

Any thoughts would be appriciated or if I can do this better way?